# Конвертация sqlite в mysql

Tags: sqlite, конвертер, mysql

Здравствуйте, нужно конвертировать sqlite в mysql, база очень большая
Перепробовал очень много вариантов, но рабочего так и не нашел
Если кто-то сталкивался - поделитесь! Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Надежнее всего писать конвертер самому;
Вот [Конвернер из sqlite в mysql](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/12793)

Answer (score 0):

Экспортировать базу в SQL. Поправить в файле типы полей при необходимости. Импортировать SQL в базу данных MySQL